# Context 'this' of EventEmitter <string> is not assigned to the 'this' method of type Observable <string>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-applications, single-page-application

I looked at the example in a GitHub repository. An application executed successfully and the written code is usually working, but I have the following error in my Visual Studio Code:

> The 'this' context of type 'EventEmitter' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable'.\n Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.\n Type '(operator: Operator) => Observable' is not assignable to type '(operator: Operator) => Observable'.\n Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.\n Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'R'.

The code that is generating the error is as follows:

```
this.notificationService.notifier
.do(message => {
  this.message = message;
  this.snackVisibility = 'visible'; 
})
.switchMap(message => Observable.timer(2000))
.subscribe(timer => this.snackVisibility = 'hidden');
```

All my service file code is below:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

export class NotificationService {
   notifier = new EventEmitter<string>();

   notify(message: string) {
      this.notifier.emit(message);
   }
}
```

Although the application works perfectly VS Code gives me the error as shown in the image:

[image]

What would be the best solution to this error?

Comment: whats your RxJs Version?

Comment: @Vikas the version of RxJs in my package.json is 5.1.0

Comment: Please include 'this.notificationService.notifier' code too, will be helpful to debug the problem

Comment: Well, @SureshKumarAriya. Here is the file code that contains the NotificationService. And I still have the problem.

Comment: EventEmitter is mainly used for Child=>Parent Communication. You should need to use Subject/of, if you are communication from service=>component.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Your code solution solved the problem and the application continues to flow well. But I did not understand what you said when the EventEmiiter is used Child => Parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Service:**

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

export class NotificationService {
   private notifier = new Subject<string>();
   public notifier$ = this.notifier.asObservable();

   notify(message: string) {
      this.notifier.next(message);
   }
}
```

**Component:**

```
this.notificationService.notifier$
.subscribe(message => {
  this.message = message;
  this.snackVisibility = 'visible'; 
  setTimeout(()=>{
   this.snackVisibility = 'hidden';
  }, 2000);
});
```